# Predicting multinom model in R - NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Tags: r, multinomial

I'm having an issue with a recurring error in a multinomial model I'm trying to create. Specifically, the error occurs when trying to predict test data with the trained model. The test and training data are split from the same dataframe, so everything about them is similar except the length of the data.

The following is what I have so far:

```
model = multinom(train$type ~ train$`12)OD280/OD315 of diluted wines` + train$`6) Total phenols`, na.action=na.omit)
model

model.pred = predict(model, newdata=train, na.action=na.omit)
model.pred

pred = predict(model, test, na.action=na.omit)
```

The last line produces the following error:

```
Error in Y[keep, ] <- Y1 : NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I've been crawling the forums for solutions, and though there are a few similar threads, none of the solutions thus far have alleviated the issue. Any insight into this error or potential solutions that would allow me to predict my data would be immensely helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really have parentheses, spaces and slashes in you column names? Yecccch.

Comment: That was not labeled by me. Believe me, it's been wildly unhelpful in a lot of cases throughout this process. However, at this time, I have been required to leave them that way. It makes me crazy too, though.

Comment: I think debugging would be a lot easier if you temporarily ran those dataframes through `check.names`. Furthermore you are violating the cardinal rule of no `"$"`'s in formulas. (That might be where you are going wrong. Use a `data=` argument.)

Comment: Hi @thedavincicoder, its difficult to assess this error without reproducible data, consider modifying your question to include data such that we can recreate the error. And yes I agree see if changing the names helps at all, If you needed to keep them that way, store them in a vector then reapply, i.e. `badnames <- colnames(train)` then `colnames(train) <- c("goodname1","goodname2",..."goodnameN")` then if you have to return it to someone with the same column names, `colnames(train) <- badnames` and viola

Comment: Oh my goodness! @IRTFM, this is the  THIRD college course I have taken in R, and you're the FIRST person to mention this about $ in formulas. That fixed the issue straight off, too. Thank you!

Comment: Most regression function assume that R formulas will be interpreted in the environment established by the `data` argument value. Using `$`'s in the formulas circumvents that expectation and creates all sorts of difficult to understand error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placeholder “answer”: It appears that one or more of my comments answered the question, so I will come back and assemble an answer to fill out this space after searching for prior answers that deal with formulas and evaluation environments.

> I think debugging would be a lot easier if you temporarily ran those dataframes through `check.names`. Furthermore you are violating the cardinal rule of no "$"'s in formulas. (That might be where you are going wrong. Use a `data=` argument.)

I spend a fair amount of time searching for a duplicate and will reference some of the "good stuff" that I found but have not really found an answer that seems to make the points I was planning to describe. There's an additional point to be made regarding constructing `Surv` objects for use in survival regression formulas that is similar in its reasoning. Still haven had time to work on the body of hte answer though.